# How to set and get a post meta array correctly

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to save to WordPress an array of values.

This is the code I am running to save it:

```
$array= new stdClass();
$array->step1 = boolval(true);
$array->step2 = boolval(false);
$array->step3 = boolval(false);
$array->step4 = boolval(false);
$array->step5 = boolval(false);
$array->step6 = boolval(false);
$array->step7 = boolval(false);
$array->step8 = boolval(false);
$array->step9 = boolval(false);
update_post_meta( $order_id, '__status', $array);
```

and when I try to `print_r($array)` the result is the following:

```
 O:8:"stdClass":9:{s:5:"step1";b:1;s:5:"step2";b:0;s:5:"step3";b:0;s:5:"step4";b:0;s:5:"step5";b:0;s:5:"step6";b:0;s:5:"step7";b:0;s:5:"step8";b:0;s:5:"step9";b:0;}
```

I would just like to add the array like this:

```
$array = [
"step1": True,
"step2": false
...
]
```

so that the result of `echo $array["step1"]` would be `true`, but that is not working.

How can I properly store my data in the database? Why is it stored as mentioned above? or how do I properly use and get the values from the format saved above to be used in the template? I tried with:

```
print_r($meta["__status"][0]['step1']['b'];
```

Is it correct ? What's wrong in this code ?

**EDIT**

Thanks for all the suggestions, I changed it this way:

```
$array= [];
$array["step1"] = true;
$array["step2"] = false;
$array["step3"] = false;
$array["step4"] = false;
$array["step5"] = false;
$array["step6"] = false;
$array["step7"] = false;
$array["step8"] = false;
$array["step9"] = false;
```

and then

```
$meta = get_post_meta($order->id);
$meta = unserialize($meta["__status"][0]);
echo $meta['step1'] ? 'true': 'false';
echo $meta['step2'] ? 'true': 'false';
```

Which prints out 1 for true

Comment: $array= new stdClass(); - seriously?

Comment: Why are you using `boolval` for boolean types?

Comment: wordpress serialized your object to store it, if you are stuck with a serialized string, you can use `maybe_unserialize()` yo get back your data. Or else see other comments about accessing values in objects vs arrays

Comment: @Sergej $array is just the name in this example, my code uses something else (sorry, I didn't notice that lol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = [
    'step1' => true,
    'step2' => false,
    'step3' => false,
    'step4' => false,
    'step5' => false,
    'step6' => false,
    'step7' => false,
    'step8' => false,
    'step9' => false
];
```

As mentioned in the comments - you are creating ab object of a stdClass, but not an array.
The field in the database, where the meta is saved - is a string (simple text line).
How would you save in a text line your object or array, which have serveral fields with non-text values (boolean values true|false) ?

That's why you see the data like that.

The data is serialized.

Look into the [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions.

They are transforming an object or an array to a text-representation to save it to a text field in the database.

When you receive the data, you need to unserialize it and you will get back your saved object or an array

Answer (score 1):

Essentialy to create array :

```
$array= [];
$array["step1"] = true;
$array["step2"] = false;
$array["step3"] = false;
$array["step4"] = false;
$array["step5"] = false;
$array["step6"] = false;
$array["step7"] = false;
$array["step8"] = false;
$array["step9"] = false;
```

boolval is unnecesary if you not cast them from different type